# Getting an error when trying to get this to work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a "Guess the Number" assignment and wrote the program, but I can not get this error to go away. "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

```
import random

randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 100)

def main():
    print ""
    number = input("I have a number between 1 and 100. Can you guess my number? Please type your first guess: ")
    guess(number)

def guess(number1): correct = False
while not correct:
        if number1 > randomNumber:
            print "Too high. Try again."
            print ""
        elif number1 < randomNumber:
            print "Too low. Try again."
            print "" 
        elif number1 == randomNumber:
            Break
        number1 = input ("What number do you guess? ")
    if number1 == randomNumber
        playAagain = raw_input ("Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ")

    if playAagain == "y": 
        main()

main()
```

The instructions say

> For this assignment you will be writing a program from scratch! 
>   Follow the directions posted below.
>
> Level 1.  Write a Python program that asks the user to guess a number
>   between 0 and 100 and give feedback that tells the user the guess was
>   too high or too low until they correctly guess the number.
>
> Level 2.  After the user correctly guesses the number, add output
>   telling the user how many guesses it took.
>
> Level 3.  The range for guessing changes after each guess.  For
>   example if the user's first guess is 50 and the feedback is that the
>   guess was to high, the next guess should be between 0 and 50.  To help
>   the user, update the new range for the guess every time they are asked
>   for another guess.
>
> Level 4.  What if the user accidentally types a number that is not
>   within then range?  Provide feedback that the guess was outside the
>   range and then do not change the range for the guesses when prompted
>   for another guess.  Let's also not count a guess outside the range in
>   their total number of guesses.
>
> Level 5.  After the user correctly guesses the number, ask if they
>   would like to play again.  If the first letter of their response is
>   'y' or 'Y' start over with a range from 0 to 100 again.  Hint: Put
>   your current loop that gets user guesses inside another loop that
>   starts the game over again.
>
> Level 6.  Each time the user guesses the correct number include
>   feedback giving the fewest number of guesses needed to correctly guess
>   the number (low/best score).  Hint:  You can initialize the low score
>   at a really high number like 100 guesses.

Comment: that meant your codes are not indented properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Specifically, provide the *entire* error message, including the information on line numbers.  Also, giving us the assignment specification is immaterial when you're trying to solve a syntax error.

Comment: correct = false should begin in a new line and indent 4 spaces and while not correct: should also indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Change the head of **guess** to this:

```
def guess(number1):
    correct = False
    while not correct:
        if number1 > randomNumber:
```

You also need a colon on your last number check:

```
if number1 == randomNumber:
```

Comment: That works great thanks! I have one other problem, When you guess the number correctly and it asks you if you want to play again if you select y or n it gives me this error message. Think you could help?Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/guess_the_number.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python27/guess_the_number.py", line 8, in main
    guess(number)
  File "C:/Python27/guess_the_number.py", line 21, in guess
    Break
NameError: global name 'Break' is not defined

Comment: You misspelled "break".  The keyword is not capitalized.  FYI, in general, a new problem requires a new question posting.  This one is just a one-character error, though.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: Thank you, and I can't vote it up or down because I don't have a "reputation" of 15 or more.